# Rails Paloma Gem - how to load page-specific javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I loaded the Paloma gem to attempt page-specific javascript.  It looks very straightforward but I must be missing something.

```
rails g paloma:setup
```

application.js:

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require paloma
```

run the command:

```
rails g paloma:add days index
```

in \app\assets\javascripts\paloma\days\index.js:

```
...
Paloma.callbacks['days']['index'] = function(params){
    // Do something here.
  alert('paloma!');
  };
})();
```

The javascript loads on the page but does not execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the order of your includes to:

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require paloma
//= require_tree .
```

I think you're currently requiring `\app\assets\javascripts\paloma\days\index.js` with the `require_tree .` line before the Paloma loader/bootstrap javascript it depends on.